# How to interact on hover with an SVG image in Phaser 3

Tags: svg, phaser-framework

I have the following code:

```js
function preload() {
  this.load.svg('table', 'assets/svg/table.svg');
}

function create {
  this.add.image(400, 300, 'table');
}
```

How can I highlight this picture when I hover over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **`pointerover`** event like so:

- **First**, declare a variable to hold the svg image.

```
let tableSvg;
```

- **Second**, preload the svg image.

```
 function preload() {
   this.load.svg('table', 'assets/svg/table.svg');
 }
```

- **Third**, add the svg image to the variable.

```
tableSvg = this.add.image(400, 300, 'table');
```

- **Fourth**, set the svg image to be interactive.

```
tableSvg.setInteractive();
```

- **Fifth**, add an mouse over event listener like so:

```
tableSvg.on('pointerover', () => {
  console.log(tableSvg)
});
```

**Edit:**

You can change the image's color like so:

```
tableSvg.on('pointerover', () => {
  // setTint method takes a color value & change the image's color accordingly
  tableSvg.setTint(185273)
});
```

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко I forgot to set the svg to interactive. I have updated it my answer.. Try it now & let me know.

Comment: Everything is ok now) Сan you tell me how to change the color of svg on hover?